# How to get data from json api url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I tried to get the data with the jQuery.getJSON() but it doesn't work.

I want to get the data from this url:
http://www.posta.com.tr/api/LiveScore/LeagueStageFixture?TournamentID=1&includeFixture=1

This is what I tried:

JS

```
 $.getJSON("http://www.posta.com.tr/api/LiveScore/LeagueStageFixture?TournamentID=1&includeFixture=1", function(data) {
    $('#data').text(data.result);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="data"></div>
```

How can I get the data and show it in a div?

Comment: Do you own the domain posta.com? Did you check your network console on the browser for errors?

Comment: no, I didn't own it.

Comment: Your browser is probably blocking a cross domain call. Check your error console

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.posta.com.tr/api/LiveScore/LeagueStageFixture?TournamentID=1&includeFixture=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.


I Get this error message.. 
How to fix this error?

Comment: You need to make a back-end call to this service and pass it to your fronted.  This direct call will not work

Comment: @shravster thanks! I will try it with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

please try this.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.posta.com.tr/api/LiveScore/LeagueStageFixture",
  type: "get", //send it through get method
  headers:{ 
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" 
    },
  data:{
        TournamentID: 1,
        includeFixture: 1
    },
  success: function(response) {
    //Do Something
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    //Do Something to handle error
  }
});
```

Comment: Which browser are you using ? same problem in all browsers ?

Comment: @Can no ajax calls to this server will work from your fronted directly. Google 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and learn more.

Comment: I use chrome, it doesn't work with jquery because the domain  blocking a cross domain call. I will try it with PHP.

Thanks all!

Comment: Hello, please try the updated code. I have added header. Post me if it work or not.

Comment: Or please try this from run menu(windows): `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`

Answer (score 0):

It works now with php. The problem was that the domain blocks connection from different hosts.